# Fastest available drive to date by booting time

Tags: boot, ssd, pci-express, ramdisk

So I'm going to build a new computer; there is a very important criteria for the specs: I want the computer to boot and start programs pretty much as fast as possible.
I looked into PCIe SSDs and read about RAM disks, however I'm not sure about what to use.

Is it worth taking a PCIe SSD that is faster at reading than others to decrease the boot time?

Or wouldn't it make that much of a difference since the boot time is throttled by the motherboard?

Comment: This question may be off-topic because it’s clear it will be outdated quite soon. Whether something is worth it depends on your (real, not emotional) requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both PCIe and SATA are pretty fast.  SATA is 6GB/second for the bus speed.  When running comparisons the boot time between the two are neck and neck.  I'm not going to go into detail since it is a very very long and drawn out discussion however I will point you to this site.  I would say it depends on your requirements.  Both are pretty close in terms of boot time.

Here is an article that has a pretty descriptive discussion on it that would be next to impossible for me to shrink and summerize.

http://www.overclock.net/t/1489684/ssd-interface-comparison-pci-express-vs-sata